# java compiling error "could not find or load main class main.java"

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I understand there are a lot of threads similar to this one, but I couldn't find the one that solved my problem. Following [`this`](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/linux-cmd.html) instruction I was able to get java in terminal and be able to compile.  I am able to "javac main.java" with no errors, but when I "java main.java", it simply says it `could not find or load main class main.java`.  I believe that my classpath is wrong but i'm not entirely sure how to fix this either.  This is what comes out when I type in `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/taka/.rvm/bin
```

and when I type `echo $CLASSPATH` it doesn't show anything.

I have also tried java -cp ./ main.java as that seemed to have worked when I compiled and ran HelloWorld.java

Comment: Compile `java vm` or `java source file`?

Comment: Are you typing `java Classname.java` or `java Classname`?

Comment: Or do you want to install java in ubuntu??

Comment: i've tried both java main.java and java main, java main didn't work, saying the command was not found.

Comment: It worked with "java -cp ./ main" but I want to know why its not working with "java main.java" when its supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

If your `javac` is successful then update your classpath environment variable and add current directory i.e. `.` in the classpath, then run the `java` as below:

```
 java main
```

**Please note:** There is no `.java` extension as you need to run `.class` file(which was generated after javac) that also without mentioning the extension. `Java` uses generated class files to execute not the original source files.

Answer (score 1):

`main.java` java is your source code . you cant run java source without compile. For compilation you should use javac command. After that it will create a main.class file which can understand by interpreter which is `java`.

So you to run your class use `java main` or `java main.class`