# Could not find or load main class com.nabinbhandari.lam.Main

Tags: java

I've read a lot of troubleshooting for similar occurrences of this error, but what is causing it for this particular .jar?
https://download.cnet.com/android/nabin-bhandari/3260-20_4-10982661-1.html

It works on Windows, but when attempting to run the file on a raspbian (linux) system running java version 1.8.0_65 with the command `java -jar Local\ Area\ Messenger\ Desktop.jar` it throws the error about not being able to find or load the main class.

The MANIFEST.MF defines `Main-Class: com.nabinbhandari.lam.Main` and there doesn't appear to be any issues with case sensitivity.

What am I missing? Do I need to install something more than Java Runtime Environment?

**Edit: In case it is not clear, I am not the developer of this file. I am simply a user trying to run the file. This question has nothing to do with Eclipse and I don't understand why people are linking to that other question. I am not running Eclipse. Please stop linking to that. Please examination the .jar file I have provided.**

Edit 2: I have followed the instructions and in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238173/2407742
It gives the error `no main manifest attribute, in test.jar` 
Is there something missing from my java runtime environment? It seems like nothing works.

Comment: Why you mentions filedropper url?? Can you explain more on that..what issue with that?

Comment: That is so people can download and examination the .jar file in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class in STS/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447721/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-sts-eclipse)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898832/java-compiling-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-main-java you may get answer from here.

Comment: I am not running Eclipse. I don't understand why that question is being linked again as relevant to the question.  @bangoria which answer are you recommending from the question you linked?

Comment: If you guys think it is a developer issue and not something I can solve as a user, please examine the file in question and let me know.

Comment: I get a 404 when I try to `wget http://www.filedropper.com/localareamessengerdesktop`

Comment: I found the file here as well. https://download.cnet.com/android/nabin-bhandari/3260-20_4-10982661-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Local Area Network Messenger application was developed using JavaFX, which is not included in the Oracle Java build for Rasperry Pi. I had to reinstall Java and then openjfx by doing the following:
`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jre-headless`
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless`
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`
`sudo apt-get install openjfx`

It runs fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this was the following:

Close Eclipse/STS
Use a file explorer on your operating system to navigate to your workspace (In my case, I'm on Windows so I used Windows Explorer)
Delete the .metadata directory (or to be safe, copy the directory somewhere else to be safe, then delete it)
Restart Eclipse/STS
Is there a more improved answer than this? I don't want to look like I'm trying to boost my own reputation points, so if someone can provide a better answer then please do so.

Comment: Can you please not copy paste answers from different questions. Just flag the question as possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447721/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-sts-eclipse

Comment: Ok...I'll do that

Comment: I'm not running eclipse nor do I have it installed. How does this pertain to the question?

Comment: Ok. So Make sure .class file should get generate of all available java files.

Comment: If there is an answer that provides a solution to this specific case for this specific .jar file, please link to that. The provided answer does not work so please do not mark as duplicate yet, people! Thanks

Comment: bangoria, it seems to generate just fine when it is run on Windows. I'm not clear on what you are recommending for running the file on Linux. I provided a link to the file in question if you would like to look at it yourself.